# Exactly duplicating a multipart form upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, requestjs

So I'm trying to upload a file using the `request/request` package. The file is `40589387` bytes in size and a .dmg file. When I upload the file using the package or anything else other than a straight HTML form it adds a few bytes to the file. So here is an example using the reuqest package:

```
uploadFile(src) {
  var url = this.storageServerAddress + '/uploadfile';
  var formData = {
    _: fs.createReadStream(src)
  };

  return request({
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    timeout: 15000,
    formData: formData,
    headers: {
      Filename: getFileName(src)
    }
  });
}
```

The when I read the `content-length` I get about 300 more bytes than the file size and it ends up corrupting the .dmg file and makes it unmountable.

If I just send it with a simple HTML form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://myurl.com" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file" /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="fileName" /><br/>
</form>
```

It sends the exact amount of bytes and does not corrupt my file. IS there anyway to exactly duplicate the html form upload? and why does the package add more bytes?

Comment: Why is this tagged `XMLHttpRequest` if you are on the server side?

Comment: What do the additional 300 bytes consist of ?